# How to get attribute values of HTML tags into a list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py, replit

I want to extract the values of the "id" attribute from a list of table rows like this one:
`<tr id="8LVPCRJGR" role="row" class="odd">`, via BeautifulSoup4. In the case of this example tag, I want the "8LVPCRJGR" part.

I tried this block of code (yes, I did import bs4 and requests modules):

```
url = "https://brawlify.com/stats/club/V8GVVR0R"
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")

tag = doc.find_all('tr')

attribute = tag['id']

print(attribute)
```

It's supposed to print out a list with all the values in it, but nothing prints. The console is blank.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues. First, tag is list of elements, specifically all the `<tr>` tag elements. Secondly, not all the `<tr>` tags have an `'id'` attribute.

So you need to put in some logic for that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://brawlify.com/stats/club/V8GVVR0R"
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")

tag = doc.find_all('tr')

attribute = [x['id'] for x in tag if 'id' in x.attrs]
```

**Output:**

```
print(attribute)
['8LVPCRJGR', '29G9VJJC', '2YP08GUG8', 'UY8PVUPL', 'VV2RRRGG', '20RQQ08U9', 'VJ00J8Y8', '200PG2VLP', '28QV0RJVV', 'YRLPJ80J', 'PRLV99U89', '9QJLQGGU', '88UYYG0U', '9PG8RUVJ', 'YP9UQ8CQ', '9J8LRGQU2', '2LPGYQVV9', '8C8CJ0UJU', 'GUGJLLRG', '9Q0VCV2J', '2RVYVL8YL', 'JP0VGC2P', '280GY2R2C', '2PRLQPJJY', '8CGJGPYJ9', '89RYCVQJ0', '80GVU28CC', 'UV0CPU2Q', '9RGG9J08J', 'Y2PQ8090R']
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find a single website or YouTube video explaining this ;-;

Comment: It is in the BeautifulSoup documentation. As well as many other SO posts

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` will return a list

you should loop through this list and extract the id attribute something like this

**Edit**

following @chitown88 comment
you can id if statement to the loop
and for @Zaid Hussain comment
apparently you can't get the `tr` tag from the HTML page because  the javascript code didn't execute before loading `requests.get(url).text` to the BeautifulSoup I would recommend trying to inspect the return of `requests.get(url).text` and if this is the case I would recommend opening the page with selenium through for example chrome driver  and passing the HTML code to the BeatifulSoup or just doing the job with Selenium

```
tags=doc.find_all('tr')
attribute= [tag['id'] for tag in tags if tag['id'] ]
print(attribute)
```

Comment: except it'll throw an error if a `tag` in `tags` doesnt have an attribute value for `'id'`

Comment: Nope. Console is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Select a bit more specific - all `<tr>` with an `id` and iterate the result set to get each `id`:

```
[x['id'] for x in soup.select('tr[id]')]
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://brawlify.com/stats/club/V8GVVR0R')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

attribute = [x['id'] for x in soup.select('tr[id]')]
print(attribute)
```

#### Output:

```
['8LVPCRJGR',
 '29G9VJJC',
 '2YP08GUG8',
 'UY8PVUPL',
 'VV2RRRGG',
 '20RQQ08U9',
 'VJ00J8Y8',
 '200PG2VLP',
 '28QV0RJVV',...]
```